# how to provide toobox and designer info for WPF Controls

Tags: wpf, user-controls, controls

I'm making a mixed UserControl and Control Library in WPF. I need to provide icons , other details and designer support etc... that is needed for WPF Control Library Authoring. Please help me.

*A well documented sample could be better*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search the web you will find there are a few good tutorials on adding design-time support. It is rather a broad subject to answer here! Take a look at the following:

[XPlorerBar : Part 2 - Adding design-time support to the WPF explorer bar control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/XPlorerBar2.aspx#heading0009)

There is also an entire MSDN chapter on the subject:

[WPF Designer Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938.aspx)